# extract html tags using Stack implementation using python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, html-parsing

> 1. Read one character at a time from the file, ignoring everything to get "<"(ignore "<" as well).
> 2. Read one character at a time, appending them to a string until ">" or white space(ignore ">" as well)
>
> the expected output should be : [....html,body,h1,/h1,/h2,/body,.....]

pretty much get all the tags from the document

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p><strong><em>Q2. HTML TAG CHECKER</em></strong></p>
    <p></p>
    <p>A <em>markup language</em> is a language that annotates text so that the
    computer can manipulate the text. Most markup languages are human readable
    because the annotations are written in a way to distinguish them from the
    text. The most important feature of a markup language is that the
    <em>tags</em> it uses to indicate annotations should be easy to distinguish
    from the document <em>content</em>.</p>
    <p>One of the most well-known markup languages is the one commonly used to
    create web pages, called <strong>HTML</strong>, or "Hypertext Markup
    Language". In HTML, tags appear in "angle brackets" such as in
    "&lt;html&gt;". When you load a Web page in your browser, you do not see
    the tags themselves: the browser interprets the tags as instructions on how
    to format the text for display.</p>
    <p>Most tags in HTML are used in pairs to indicate where an effect starts
    and ends. For example:</p>
    <p>&lt;p&gt;
    this is a paragraph of text written in HTML
    &lt;/p&gt;</p>
    <p>Here &lt;p&gt; represents the start of a paragraph, and &lt;/p&gt;
    indicates where that paragraph ends.</p>
    <p>Other tags include &lt;b&gt; and &lt;/b&gt; that are used to place the
    enclosed text in <strong>bold</strong> font, and &lt;i&gt; and &lt;/i&gt;
    indicate that the enclosed text is <em>italic</em>.</p>
    <p>Note that "end" tags look just like the "start" tags, except for the
    addition of a backslash &lsquo;/&rsquo;after the &lt; symbol.</p>
    <p>Sets of tags are often nested inside other sets of tags. For example, an
    <em>ordered list</em> is a list of numbered bullets. You specify the start
    of an ordered list with the tag &lt;ol&gt;, and the end with &lt;/ol&gt;.
    Within the ordered list, you identify items to be numbered with the tags
    &lt;li&gt; (for "list item") and &lt;/li&gt;. For example, the following
    specification:</p>
    <p>&lt;ol&gt;</p>
    <p>&lt;li&gt;First item&lt;/li&gt;</p>
    <p>&lt;li&gt;Second item&lt;/li&gt;</p>
    <p>&lt;li&gt;Third item&lt;/li&gt;</p>
    <p>&lt;/ol&gt;</p>
    <p>would result in the following:</p>
    <ol>
        <li>First item</li>
        <li>Second item</li>
        <li>Third item</li>
    </ol>
```

Stack.py:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
    def is_empty(self):
        return self.items == []
    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)
    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()
    def peek(self):
        return self.items[-1]

    #Returns string representation of contents of stack
    def __str__(self):
        return
```

main.py

```
from Stack import Stack

#Processes HTML file and returns list of HTML tag objects
def process_html_file(file_name):
    tag_list = []
    s =Stack()
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        all_lines = []
        # loop through all lines using f.readlines() method
        for line in f.readlines():
            new_line = []
            # this is how you would loop through each alphabet
            for chars in line:
                new_line.append(chars)
            all_lines.append(new_line)
```

Comment: Why would it skip `head` and `title`?

Comment: Sorry James, I just edited it the question. I would want to get all the tags out of the document without the "<" and ">"

Comment: Please edit again with what you are currently getting with this code and the steps you have done to debug the issues you're having. Right now, all you've done is add lines of text to a list.

Comment: Also, the last answer you had already does what you want. Do you **need** a stack? You can just append the regex results to a stack... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52239686/extract-html-tags-from-a-text-file-through-iteration-and-append-them-to-a-list-a